# Return a copy of a file as a file stream

Tags: vb.net, file, file-io, copy, filestream

I'm building an application that will serve up a file as a `FileStream`.  I need to be able to do this without locking the source file, because the file stream may remain in use by the client for some amount of time, and the application may need to perform subsequent write operations on the source file.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to provide an independent copy of the file as a file stream rather than the source file itself.

Here is a POC I started with:

```
Friend Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim fs = GetServerFile()
    Dim t = SomeOperationThatOverwritesServerFile()

    'just simulate using the file for some period of time, 
    'even thought this probably isn't needed bc it's already locked anyway.
    For i = 1 To 10
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next

    fs.Close()
End Sub

Friend Function GetServerFile() As FileStream
    GetServerFile = File.OpenRead(serverFilePath)
End Function

Friend Async Function SomeOperationThatOverwritesServerFile() As Task
    'just simulate something that overwrites the server file with fresh data.
    For i = 1 To 5
        Await Task.Run(Sub() File.Copy(newSourceFilePath, serverFilePath, True))
        Await Task.Delay(2000)
    Next
End Function
```

This code throws an `IOException` on `Await Task.Run(Sub() File.Copy(newSourceFilePath, serverFilePath, True))` because the file is locked by the client.  Fair enough.

Now I'm looking at the `FileStream.CopyTo()` method, however, I'm not sure any of the `FileStream` constructor overloads will work:

```
Friend Function GetServerFile() As FileStream
    GetServerFile = File.OpenRead(serverFilePath).CopyTo(New FileStream(WHICH OVERLOAD DO I USE?))
End Function
```

They all take a `String` path to a file or a `SafeFileHandle`.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out.  I mistakenly thought that the `CopyTo` method takes a `FileStream` when in fact it takes a `Stream` (which makes sense because `CopyTo` is defined in `Stream`, not `FileStream`), so I can use a `MemoryStream` like this:

```
Friend Function GetServerFile() As MemoryStream
    GetServerFile = New MemoryStream()

    Using inputStream = File.OpenRead(serverFilePath)
        inputStream.CopyTo(GetServerFile)
    End Using
End Function
```